# Adrotator issues with AdDuplex

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, adrotator

I am trying to use AdRotator in my Windows Store application and I just installed it using the Nuget Package manager. I tried to run my app without adding any controls or code behind in XAML/C# Windows store app and it crashes throwing an exception about AdDuplex.

To be more precise I get the following exception

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in AdRotatorWin8.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'AdDuplex.Windows, Version=8.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=447cab5ae9276daf' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I do not plan to use AdDuplex in my app but without adding any code about AdDuplex I keep getting exceptions.
After uninstalling adrotator everything works fine again.

After checking with the packages output window AdDuplex was installed alongside AdRotator. How do I make my app work though?
My default Ad settings file consists only of this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AdSettings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CultureDescriptors>
    <AdCultureDescriptor CultureName="default">
      <Probabilities Probability="50" AdType="PubCenter" AppID="test_client" SecondaryID="Image_728x90" />
    </AdCultureDescriptor>
  </CultureDescriptors>
</AdSettings
```

With numbers and IDs set up properly but obviously I cannot share them here. 
The issues persists no matter what I do.

I tried downloading adDuplex but the only availiable version in Nuget is 8.0.5 which in theory should work (since the error is of an earlier version of AdDuplex) but still doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out said version of AdDuplex had Issues with AdRotator and Adrotator has been updated to accomodate the new changes

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions in this url : http://darkgenesis.zenithmoon.com/adrotator-for-windows-8/

I believe that you have to change

> defaultApSettings.xml

remove AdDuplex and set the Ad service that you are going to use.

An alternative solution is to just download the AdDuplex package using Nuget but I believe that is not the best choice if you have already decided that you are not going to use it.